# odoo one2many default not set

Tags: python, odoo, default, openerp-8

I wrote a wizard which form view should show a one2many field with rows taken from *context['active_ids'].*

I set the one2many default correctly, but when the form opens, no rows are showed.

Did I miss anything? (I apologize for code bad indentation)

```
class delivery_wizard(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'as.delivery.wizard'

address = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
details = fields.One2many('as.delivery.detail.wizard', 'delivery')
carrier = fields.Many2one('delivery.carrier')

@api.model
def default_get(self, fields_list):
    res = models.TransientModel.default_get(self, fields_list)
    ids = self.env.context.get('active_ids', [])
    details = self.env['as.delivery.detail'].browse(ids)
    dwz = self.env['as.delivery.detail.wizard']
    dws = []
    for detail in details:
        dw = dwz.create({
            'production': detail.production_id.id,
            'quantity': detail.quantity,
            'actual_quantity': detail.quantity,
            'enabled': detail.production_id.state == 'done',
            'delivery': self.id,
        })
        dws.append(dw.id)

    res['details'] = [(6, False, dws)]
    res['address'] = details[0].delivery_id.address_id.id
    return res

class delivery_detail_wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'as.delivery.detail.wizard'

    production = fields.Many2one('as.production')
    quantity = fields.Float()
    actual_quantity = fields.Float()
    force = fields.Boolean()
    enabled = fields.Boolean()
    delivery = fields.Many2one('as.delivery.wizard')
```

Comment: Are you sure about using self.id inside default_get ? I would bet that the object has no id yet. I think that the id comes after creating the object. In order to create the object you need the default values. I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem may be there :

```
res['details'] = **[(6, False, dws)]**
```

Your details field is a One2many field, [(6,0, [IDS])] are for Many2many.
In your case, you don't need to assign anything to the details fields ; it's a One2many, so it's automatic as you already created the corresponding Many2one record (dw).

[Little reminder from the doc](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html#osv.osv.osv.write) :

- For Many2many

> For a many2many field, a list of tuples is expected. Here is the list
> of tuple that are accepted, with the corresponding semantics
>
> (0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created
> with the given values dictionary
>
> (1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write
> *values* on it)
>
> (2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id =
> ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and
> the link to it as well)
>
> (3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID
> (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete
> the target object itself)
>
> (4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a
> relationship)
>
> (5)                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked
> records)
>
> (6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5)
> then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
>
> Example:    [(6, 0, [8, 5, 6, 4])] sets the many2many to ids [8, 5, 6,
> 4]

- And One2many  :

> (0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created
> with the given values dictionary
>
> (1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write
> *values* on it)
>
> (2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id =
> ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and
> the link to it as well)
>
> Example:    [(0, 0, {'field_name':field_value_record1, ...}), (0, 0,
> {'field_name':field_value_record2, ...})]

Also, try to follow [odoo guidelines](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/guidelines.html#symbols) for Many2One/One2many fields if you want your code to be easily understandable by other people :

> One2Many and Many2Many fields should always have **_ids** as suffix (example: sale_order_line_ids)
>
> Many2One fields should have **_id** as suffix (example : partner_id, user_id, ...)

Comment: I tried with res['details'] = [(0, 0, dws)] with dws an array of dict, but then i realized i just needed res['details'] = dws. About guidelines, you're right but with new API 8 IMHO this should not be needed anymore because "ids" are not just numbers, but whole objects. For example the notation object_id.id is redundant. It could have sense for backward compatibility...

Comment: I agree that it feels a little deprecated now, but well, object_record / object_records seems a bit verbose doesn't it ? ;)
Perhaps they will point to something like object_rd / object_rds in the future, who knows.

Comment: It seems that you don't need 'delivery': self.id
In fact self.id==False on that moment
As you have realized you need just res['details'] = dws
There is some kind of magic that assign 'delivery' field to your child entities with self.id after inserting the parent object.