# Set default values for One2many field

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have a class `student_student` which have a one2many field`result_ids` defined like the following:

```
    result_ids = fields.One2many("schoolresults.detail", "student_id", "School Results", default="_get_subjects")
```

and

```
def _get_subjects(self):
     cr = self.pool.cursor()
     self.env
     return self.pool.get('schoolresults.subject').search(cr, self.env.uid, [])
```

in the other side I have a class `schoolresults_subject`:

```
class schoolresults_subject(models.Model):
    _name = "schoolresults.subject"
    _description = "Student's subjects."
    name = fields.Char("Subject")

class schoolresults_detail(models.Model):
    _name = "schoolresults.detail"
    _description = "Student's results."
    student_id = fields.Many2one("student.student", "Student", ondelete="cascade")
    subject_id = fields.Many2one("schoolresults.subject", "Subject")
    result = fields.Float("Result", compute='_compute_value', store=True)
```

What I'm trying to do is to fill the result_ids with a subjects list from the last class, whenever the user trying to create a new student profile, using the the `default` parameter in the one2many field.
But whenever I try to create a student profile I get this error `Wrong values for student.student.result_ids`.
Please is there anyway to achieve that?
[image]

**PS. I'm using Odoo 9**

Comment: I'm trying to set a default set of values(subjects) each time a student profile created.I'm not trying to filter existing data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could do this by overriding the `default_get` method:

```
def default_get(self, fields):
    res = super(student_student, self).default_get(fields)
    srd = self.env['schoolresults.detail']
    ids=[]
    school_result={'subject_id':1,'result':0} #dict for fields and their values
    sr = srd.create(school_result)
    ids.append(sr.id)


    res['result_ids'] = ids
    return res
```

This is how to override `default_get` for one2many field.

Credit goes to:[Default values for one2many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607934/odoo-one2many-default-not-set)

Comment: DId you edit your code after last edit (link to another question)? Because the line `res['result_ids'] = [0,0,VALS]` should be more like `res['result_ids'] = [(0,0,VALS)]`

Comment: This code is not working smoothly, I will put the right one.

Answer (score 5):

I don't get your requirements here fully, but try something like the following:

```py
def _get_subjects(self):
    subjects = self.env['schoolresults.subject'].search([])
    details = self.env['schoolresults.detail']
    for subject in subjects:
        details |= details.new({'subject_id': subject.id})
    return details
```

But explaining the error message: you're returning a RecordSet of `schoolresults.subject` but your field `result_ids` has the comodel `schoolresults.detail`. That's just wrong ;-)

Comment: I agree with you, I'm trying something complex.However I didn't understand the operator '|=', and your code didn't work unfortunately.I think that I should override the 'default_get' function, I will try this and see.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally got the solution by overloading the default_get method and it worked fine.

Comment: Share your result with us :-) The `|` operator works with `RecordSets`. You can combine two `RecordSets` with it ([doc](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#recordsets)).

Comment: I didn't have this in mind.I posted a fix for the problem but still not working fine

Answer (score 1):

**Please read this If you want to set the default values of one2many field from action**, you can create a list of tuple with the same format we use for create or write one2many field and then you can pass it to context.
You can copy your context-

```
context = self.env.context.copy()
```

Prepare one2many values like this--

```
pr_lines = []
        for pr_line in pr_obj.line_ids: #loop for multiple lines.
            pr_lines.append((0,0, {
                'purchase_request_id' : pr_obj.id,
                'product_id' : pr_line.product_id.id, 
                'description' : pr_line.name,
                'qty_transfer' : pr_line.product_qty,
                'uom_id' : pr_line.product_uom_id.id,
            }))
```

You can update your context like this-

```
    context.update({
            'default_warehouse_id': self.approving_matrix_id.warehouse.id,
            'default_internal_transfer_receipt': pr_lines,
        })
```

in the action you can pass context like
'context' : context,

Answer (score 0):

```
result_ids = fields.Many2many("schoolresults.detail", "student_id", "School Results", default="_get_subjects")

def get_default_lines(self):
    obj = self.env['your.class.name'].search([])
    return obj
```

Try adding many2many field to your class.